# Unable to view/run the integration-gateway tasks after importing a freshly created integration gateway app

Tags: guidewire

I am trying to set up a basic integration gateway project .
Below are the steps that I have followed.

1. Create a new integration gateway app from GCC
2. Cloned the project and imported the project as a gradle project in Intellij IDE

Unable to run the command *gradlew runIntegrationApp *, also I don't see the gradle tasks related to integration-gateway in the studio.
Below is the error message that i get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ekkt.jpg)

Can someone let me know what might be missing , as I am unable to find any solution in Guidewire cloud documentation.
Regards,
Raja

I am expecting the **gradlew runIntegrationApp** command to be available to be run .

Answer (score 4):

It looks like all dependencies are not loaded into the IG project locally. Can you add your BitBucket credentials locally under `igArtifactRepoUsername` and `igArtifactRepoPassword` in the `gradle.properties` file?

Reload the Gradle dependencies again before attempting to run the task again.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Uday

Comment: Hi Uday, Thanks for looking into this. I have these credentials in my environment variables , also added these in gradle.property , but no luck . Since the maven artifact repo is a rest API endpoint I feel the general bitbucket credential wont work. Probably I need a client Id and secret for calling the API to get  the jars from maven repo. Regards, Raja